# Making a query result equal to zero when a condition is null

Tags: php, mysql

I believe the query below should work.  However, when I run it, the results are blank.  I think this is happening since for now, the table "comment" is empty.  So there is no instance where s.submissionid = c.submissionid.  I would like to have the query below to work even if there if no s.submissionid that equals a c.submissionid.  In this case, I would like countComments to equal zero.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username, count(c.comment) AS countComments
             FROM submission AS s,
                  login AS l, 
                  comment AS c,
            WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid
              AND s.submissionid = c.submissionid
         GROUP BY s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
         ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
            LIMIT 10";          


$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/index.php?submission='.$row["title"].'">'.$row["countComments"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Did you try an outer join?  I think you will get a 1 instead of 0 if you use this exact select, but you can change the count... to make it right.

Comment: MJB, after I read the question, I tried that, but the row doesn't appear in the result set for me.  a1ex07's answer works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username, count(c.comment) AS countComments
         FROM submission AS s,
              login AS l
         LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON (s.submissionid = c.submissionid)
        WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid              
     GROUP BY s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
     ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
        LIMIT 10"
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  The problem is not the query, but that there will be many instances where s.submissionid will have no corresponding c.submissionid.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your queries at the command line or through something like phpMyAdmin/HeidiSQL/etc. to make sure you are getting the right data and the syntax is correct.

You are missing a few commas, one after s.submissionid on the select line and again on the group by line.

a1ex07's query should work if you add the missing commas.